# How to handle token expiry in token based authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am using token based authentication (OAuth 2.0). If user is valid a token is generated successfully. All this is fine.

But there is Logout functionality. My question is not how to delete the token (its not possible).

But when I generated a token I had set an expiration time. Now if user wishes to logout all I am thinking to set the token expiration time to Date.now. So that if user tries to logon with the same token, he gets an access denied exception.

Something like this - `https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=auth.expireSession&format=json&access_token=<access_token>`

Thanks.